# how to compare two string values from custom adapter in android?

Tags: java, android, equals, string-comparison

I have made a custom ArrayAdapter,I am getting an arrayList in taht adapter,I want to put a condition that two values from arrayList(payer_id and Payee_id) are equal or not,If equal print "equal",Else "Not qual"..My Code is as below:but its all time goes to not equal condition..Please help me save me.
**code**

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> receivePaymentArray;
  if (receivePaymentArray.get(paramInt).get(Const.TAG_PAYEE_ID).equalsIgnoreCase(receivePaymentArray.get(paramInt).get(Const.TAG_PAYER_ID))) {

            System.out.println("::::::::::::::::::::::SAME IDS::::::::::::::::");


        } else {
            System.out.println("::::::::::::::::::::::different ids:::::::::::::::");

        }
```

Comment: just do --> if(receivePaymentArray.get(paramInt).get(Const.TAG_PAYEE_ID).equalsIgnoreCase(receivePaymentArray.get(paramInt).get(Const.TAG_PAYER_ID)))

Comment: Why don't you check what those two values print out. Also, you don't need the `==true` at the end, any `if` or `while` statement will automatically check if something is true.

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar-i have changed as per you told...but it altime goes to else part..even values are same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the variables you are comparing strings or integers.. id s are usually int but your question implies they are strings..

Strings compared using == will always return false because they are not the same object.. with strings you have to use '.equals("something")

Comment: Are your constants type enum?

Comment: receivePaymentArray.get(paramInt).get(Const.TAG_PAYEE_ID)  looks like an array of arrays? can you show us your arrayList data model?

Comment: did you post it yet?  i don't see anything?  guessing you probably solved it.

Comment: What type is Const.TAG_PAYEE_ID - is that an enum?  because if it is you should write get(Const.TAG_PAYEE_ID.name()) or get(Const.TAG_PAYEE_ID.toString());  its hard to debug this with out more of your code

Comment: pls see my edit...i am getting those values from arrayList that i diclared in first line of my code..

Comment: this answer was accepted, and thats great for me, but what was the solution?

Answer (score 0):

As you say they are strings try doing

```
get(Const.TAG_PAYEE_ID).toString().trim().equals(get(Const.TAG_PAYEE_ID).toString().trim())
```

might solve your issue. Just added .toString().trim() to both parameters get statements.